# WPF DataGrid cell slyle change after update

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, xaml-binding

I have a DataGrid with dynamicaly generated columns and I need to change style of cells whose values have changed after some manipulations.

The ItemsSource for DataGrid is defined as `List<MyTableRow>`, where

```
public class MyTableRow
{
    private string[] _values;
    private string _rowHeader;

    // getters and setters here
}
```

DataGrid columns are generated with following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < source[0].Values.Length; i++)
{
    var col = new DataGridTextColumn();
    var binding = new Binding("Values[" + i + "]");
    col.Binding = binding;
    col.CanUserSort = false;
    this.dataGrid.Columns.Add(col);
    this.dataGrid.Columns[i].Header = columnNames[i];
}
```

Resulting DataGrid looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Rm9m.png)

The problem arises when I try to highlight (bold text or colored background) cells whose values in ItemsSource have changed. This i sthe point where my question splits into two:

1. Is there some "built-in" way to do smth with changed cells? (maybe with `ObservableColletion` or smth else)
2. If no, how can i highlight separate cells based either on their indexes or their values

I tried to do this with xaml styles and/or triggers, but it turned out that i do not know what value blinding should I pass to converter

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Background" 
            Value="{Binding <!-- some proper binding here -->, 
                    Converter={StaticResource ValueToBrushConverter}}"/>
</Style>
```

Other solutions found on SO either have the same "problem" with binding or just don't work. What can I do to highlight just *one* cell and not whole row/column? I can change ItemsSource, `MyTableRow` fields and/or columns' generation code, if necessary

Can anyone please help me out? Been a few days since I stuck with this problem

---

**UPDATE** Found solution

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally find out how to do what I want. The solution is kinda "dirty", but works fine for me.
I added non-breaking space character to every cell I need to highlight

`private const string NBSP = "\u00A0"`

All that's left to do after that is to create value converter. So I added `MultiBinding` in my XAML:

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ValueToBrushMultiConverter}" >
                    <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}" />
                    </MultiBinding.Bindings>
                 </MultiBinding
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

Сonverter defined as:

```
public class ValueToBrushMultiConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        private const string NBSP = "\u00A0";
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var cell = (DataGridCell)values[0];
            var dgRow = (DataGridRow)values[1];

            var test = (dgRow.Item as TableRow<string, string>).Values[cell.Column.DisplayIndex];

            if (test.Contains(NBSP))
                return System.Windows.Media.Brushes.PaleGreen;
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;           
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps someone!